# Instantiating multiple buttons from a for loop throwing error

Tags: java, android, button, instantiation

im trying to instantiate multiple buttons from a for loop but im getting the following error:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I have tried removing the view but only 1 button instantiates then. I have looked at other solutions with the same error but they don't work for me.. any suggestions would be great. Thanks ..

Here is the Code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            speakOut("setting devices");
            DeviceHelper db = new DeviceHelper(getActivity());
            List<String> devs = db.getAllDevices();
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("lock", "drawable",getActivity().getPackageName());
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

            int amm = devs.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < amm; i++) {
                String nas2 = devs.get(i);
                 //layout.removeView(imageView);
                Log.v("NAS", " db info for devices " + nas2);
                imageView.setTag(ii);
                imageView.setX(t + 100);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);
                imageView.setImageResource(id);

                layout.addView(imageView);

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this line inside the for loop:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
```

Comment: If it solves your problem sign it as response :D it really helps. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Error Says You are adding a View which is child that is already on the screen has it's parent defined so first remove that.So in short you should never add same view object more then once to it's parent.

As your `imageView` is declared outside the loop and you are continuously adding that view to the layout parent which is restricting you from doing so.

So your declaration of `imageview` should be inside loop which will create new `imageView` every time.

***EDIT For Your Comment***

You can implement listener like this

```
public class YouClass extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
//Your Code
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    //Applicable to all buttons which has setOnClickListener(this)
    //Get Data from View arg0 to determine which button has been clicked
    }
}
```

And use `button.setOnClickListener(this);` in loop. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got it working with (new onClickListener) .. thanks for the info :-)